# application does not run in background mode ios

Tags: iphone, ios

My issue is, I implement an alert that allows to tell the user that there is no internet connection when opening the application, a white view displays with the alert.
My code is:

```
Reachability * reach = [Reachability reachabilityWithHostname:@"www.google.com"];

if([reach isReachable])
{
UIStoryboard *storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"MainStoryboard_iPhone" bundle:[NSBundle mainBundle]];
MFSideMenuContainerViewController *container = (MFSideMenuContainerViewController *)self.window.rootViewController;
UINavigationController *navigationController = [storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"navigationController"];

UIViewController *rightSideMenuViewController = [storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"rightSideMenuViewController"];

[container setRightMenuViewController:rightSideMenuViewController];
[container setCenterViewController:navigationController];
}
else
{
    connection = @"Please connect to Internet";
    [self showAlarm:connection];
    [reach startNotifier];
}

    - (void)showAlarm:(NSString *)text
{
    UIAlertView *alertView = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Connection"
        message:text delegate:self
        cancelButtonTitle:@"الغاء"
        otherButtonTitles:nil];
    [alertView show];

}
```

The method above, allows to alert the user if there is no connection like the screenshot below:
[image]

Now, if I have internet connection, and try to open the application (click on the application icon), the white page displays (still in background),

[image]

Because the last time I open the application, there is no connection, so the white page displays, so when I open the application again (and now I have internet), the main page of the application must launched, but because it saves the last opened view, so the white page displays again, if I double click on the main button of the iphone and close the application, and run it again it works fine,
Hope You got me now.
Is it true If I turn the (application does not run in background) to YES? or there is another solution you suggest, and if yes please tell me what does this option (app doesn't run in background) do? and if it has inconvenients, is it safe to use it?
Thank you

Comment: Please share code, what have you done so far?

Comment: Plz elaborate your question...After reading your question I can't make it out what you want exactly?? Your white background is a problem or your strugling with checking the internet connectivity or what?

Answer (score 0):

Try this in your class, whenever you are coming again.

```
- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver: self  selector: @selector(handleEnterForeground:) name: @"UIApplicationDidBecomeActiveNotification" object: nil];
}

- (void) handleEnterForeground: (NSNotification*) sender
{
    [self checkYourConnection_Method];
}
```

**`NSNotification`** tells application if it'll come in foreground from background.

Then call method for checking 'Internet Connection' again.

Hopefully, this will help you.

Thanks.